# How do I change the border size for a table in Dear ImGui?

Tags: c++, border, imgui, thickness

How do I change the border size for a table in **Dear ImGui**?

By default, in Dear ImGui, the thickness of the **table borders** is 1 pixel (this can be seen if you draw the table). I want to change this value. How can this be done? And is it possible at all?

I didn't find the necessary field in the enum ImGuiStyleVar_ for the Push_Style_Var() function :(

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbeld upon this as well...
In imgui_tables.cpp the table bordersize is currently fixed:

```
static const float TABLE_BORDER_SIZE                     = 1.0f;    // FIXME-TABLE: Currently hard-coded because of clipping assumptions with outer borders rendering.
```

So you either need to change this value or submit a issue/request on the github repo.